# Manejo básico de excepciones en JAVA, no me funciona el try-catch

Tags: java, excepciones, try-catch

Estoy intentando capturar varias excepciones, pero sin éxito. Cuando introduzco un carácter en lugar de un entero salta una excepción y el programa cae. ¿Por qué no entra en el catch? Cuando divido por 0 aunque el programa no cae, tampoco no entra en el  `System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero!");` ¿Por qué no entra en el catch?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class PROG04_ejerc5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean salir = false; //declaro variable que me permitirá salir del programa
        int numdivisiones = 0;

        while (!salir) {

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Escribe -1 en dividendo y en divisor para salir");
            
            System.out.println("Introduce un número entero que será el dividendo: ");
            int dividendo = teclado.nextInt(); //

            System.out.println("Introduce un número entero que será el divisor: ");
            int divisor = teclado.nextInt(); //
            
            try {
                float resultado = (float)dividendo / divisor;
                
                System.out.printf("El resultado de la división es: %1.3f \n",resultado);
              
                
            }catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("No has introducido un número entero"+ex);
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero!"+ e);
            }finally{
            System.out.println("Has realizado "+numdivisiones+" divisiones");
            }
            if (dividendo== -1 && divisor== -1)  salir =true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En java, si intentas dividir un *entero* (`int`) entre 0, obtienes una `AritmeticException`, efectivamente. Pero si intentas dividir un `float` entre 0, obtienes `infinity` y no una excepción :) Puedes comprobarlo poniendo `System.out.println(3f/0);`, el resultado será `Infinity`. Sin embargo quita la `f` del primer número y verás la excepción que esperabas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el comentario que tienes de Benito-B explica lo que ocurre, que en `float` no realiza lo mismo con `int`. `Infinity` puede incluso ser tanto negativo como positivo.

Si deseas realizar con `float`, una manera es con un `catch` crear tu la excepción.

```
        try {
        if (dividendo == 0 || divisor == 0) {
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero... Cerrando programa!");
            throw new ArithmeticException(); // Lanzar SOLO esto lo cierra.
        }
        } catch (ArithmeticException ae){
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero...");
        }
```

También indicarte que `int numdivisiones` lo tienes en 0 constantemente, así que te faltara terminar algunas partes del programa. Animo y espero haberte ayudado.

Edit: Perdón que no me fije que también pides excepción cuando se ingresa una letra, esa es otra excepción que debes indicar, ya que son dos diferentes. Siendo un `InputMismatchException`, puedes poner otro catch.

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
System.out.println("Error, ingreso de letra o numero decimal...");}
```

La razón porque no te saltaba el `catch` es debido a que tienes el `try` **mal colocado, debes indicarlo antes de poner el dato ya que Java lanzara la excepción de inmediato** al tener una variable con excepción no controlada. Yo lo he indicado en el primer `System.out.print`.